# PHP array_key_exists condition not printing after statement

Tags: php, laravel

I am calling an external api endpoint and it returns an XML. I am trying to catch if the the translated json from the xml has a current array key since it does not have an `status` column so I manually trying to do some condition.

Here is what I tried

My code in transforming xml to json and printing the response

```
            $parsed_xml = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response));
            $finalJson = json_decode($parsed_xml,true);
            dd($finalJson);
            if(isset($finalJson['ErrorResponse'])){
               dd('Error response');
            }else{
               dd($finalJson['GetTransportContentResult']['TransportContent']['TransportHeader']['IsPartnered']);
            }
```

When I run `php artisan tinker` and call the controller method (without the conditions for checking the response, i used `dd($finalJson)`, here are the outputs

If the response has error, the translated xml becomes like this

```
array:2 [
  "Error" => array:3 [
    "Type" => "Sender"
    "Code" => "AccessDenied"
    "Message" => "AuthToken is not valid for SellerId and AWSAccountId."
  ]
  "RequestID" => "be9742cd-516b-43f7-9a9e-bee00ad07b4f"
]
```

But if it  is successful the response is

```
array:2 [
  "GetTransportContentResult" => array:1 [
    "TransportContent" => array:3 [
      "TransportHeader" => array:4 [
        "SellerId" => "AZZQLCSVQ753J"
        "ShipmentId" => "FBA15XJRFN14"
        "IsPartnered" => "true"
        "ShipmentType" => "LTL"
      ]
```

I dont know if I add the if-else code i wrote, it returns `true` in tinker and it does not go to print the `dd('Error response')` I also tried using `array_key_exists('Error',$finalJson)` but it does the same thing. Can someone tell me if I am doing the correct thing or I missed something. Thanks a lot.

EDIT: @RigsFolly want me to show the raw result of `$response`, I just used `dd($response)` and run the method in tinker and these are the results

If the response is success

```
<GetTransportContentResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentInboundShipment/2010-10-01/">\n
  <GetTransportContentResult>\n
    <TransportContent>\n
      <TransportHeader>\n
        <SellerId>AZZQLCSVQ753J</SellerId>\n
        <ShipmentId>FBA15XJRFN14</ShipmentId>\n
        <IsPartnered>true</IsPartnered>\n
        <ShipmentType>LTL</ShipmentType>\n
      </TransportHeader>\n
      <TransportDetails>\n
        <PartneredLtlData>\n
          <IsBillOfLadingAvailable>true</IsBillOfLadingAvailable>\n
          <FreightReadyDate>Tue Jan 12 00:00:00 GMT 2021</FreightReadyDate>\n
          <AmazonReferenceId>12113840411</AmazonReferenceId>\n
          <PreviewPickupDate>Wed Jan 13 00:00:00 GMT 2021</PreviewPickupDate>\n
          <PreviewFreightClass>175.0</PreviewFreightClass>\n
          <PartneredEstimate>\n
            <Amount>\n
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>\n
              <Value>229.95</Value>\n
            </Amount>\n
            <VoidDeadline>2021-01-12T17:34:56Z</VoidDeadline>\n
          </PartneredEstimate>\n
          <SellerDeclaredValue>\n
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>\n
            <Value>1006.40</Value>\n
          </SellerDeclaredValue>\n
          <PalletList>\n
            <member>\n
              <IsStacked>false</IsStacked>\n
              <Weight>\n
                <Unit>pounds</Unit>\n
                <Value>344.0</Value>\n
              </Weight>\n
              <Dimensions>\n
                <Unit>IN</Unit>\n
                <Width>40.0</Width>\n
                <Length>48.0</Length>\n
                <Height>45.0</Height>\n
              </Dimensions>\n
            </member>\n
          </PalletList>\n
          <BoxCount>34</BoxCount>\n
          <Contact>\n
            <Phone>(510) 970-9910</Phone>\n
            <Name>Mario</Name>\n
            <Email>Orders@orionlog.com</Email>\n
          </Contact>\n
          <TotalWeight>\n
            <Unit>pounds</Unit>\n
            <Value>344.0</Value>\n
          </TotalWeight>\n
        </PartneredLtlData>\n
      </TransportDetails>\n
      <TransportResult>\n
        <TransportStatus>CONFIRMED</TransportStatus>\n
      </TransportResult>\n
    </TransportContent>\n
  </GetTransportContentResult>\n
  <ResponseMetadata>\n
    <RequestId>313995bb-b198-469d-9c95-af4feb1a0745</RequestId>\n
  </ResponseMetadata>\n
</GetTransportContentResponse>\n
```

If it has an error

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>\n
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentInboundShipment/2010-10-01/">\n
  <Error>\n
    <Type>Sender</Type>\n
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>\n
    <Message>AuthToken is not valid for SellerId and AWSAccountId.</Message>\n
  </Error>\n
  <RequestID>b0df9b31-fe36-4936-883e-1c8b19157ba9</RequestID>\n
</ErrorResponse>\n
```

Comment: Can you show us the raw `$response`

Comment: you mean the xml sir? @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xmlns` is a definitions of the document not part of the documents contents.

So you are testing the wrong part of the XML, instead try

```
if(isset($finalJson['Error'])){
    echo 'Error response';
}else{
    echo $finalJson['GetTransportContentResult']['TransportContent']['TransportHeader']['IsPartnered'];
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your answer sir. It kinda works when the result has an error but when it doesnt have an error. It also returns `true` and not going to the `else` part. anything i missed?

Comment: Can you show ALL of a good response then please, what you showed is not even valid XML

Comment: okay sir im sorry. I edited the question pasting the whole results for a response without error

Comment: Again, not valid xml

Comment: sorry sir i was forgotten i am getting the column `IsPartnered` and it only returns true or false. I was confused becaseu of the method before that returns `true`